# Select IDs from multiple rows where column values satisfy one condition but not another

Tags: sql

Hello I have the following problem.

I have a table like the one in this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f3866)
This table defines a relationship and it contains IDs from two other tables

example values

```
| FirstID  | SecondID  | 
|  1       |     1     |
|  1       |     2     |
|  1       |     3     |
|  2       |     1     |
|  2       |     2     |
|  2       |     3     |
|  2       |     4     |
|  2       |     5     |
|  3       |     1     |
|  3       |     2     |
|  3       |     3     |
```

I want to select all the FirstIDs that satisfy the following criteria.
**Their corresponding SecondIDs are in the range 1-3 AND NOT in the range 4-5**

For example in this case we would want FirstIDs 1 and 3.

I have tried the following queries

```
SELECT FirstID from table 
WHERE SecondID IN (1,2,3) AND SecondID NOT IN (4,5)

SELECT  FirstID,SecondID
FROM(
   SELECT FirstID, SecondID
   FROM  table
   WHERE  SecondID in (1,2,3,4,5) ) 
WHERE SecondID NOT IN (4,5)
```

but I don't get the correct results I am aiming for.

What is the correct query to get the data I want?

Comment: @Eric I get the wrong results. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FirstID
FROM table
WHERE SecondId in (1,2,3) --Included values
AND FirstID NOT IN (SELECT FirstID FROM test
                    WHERE SecondId IN (4,5)) --Excluded values
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `min()` and `max()`:

```
select firstid
from t
group by firstid
having min(secondId) between 1 and 3 and
       max(secondid) between 1 and 3;
```

Assuming 1 is the minimum, then this can be simplified to:

```
having max(secondid) <= 3;
```

For arbitrary ranges, you can use `sum(case)`:

```
having sum(case when secondId between 1 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when secondId between 4 and 5 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :). It is not guaranteed that the SecondIDs will be consecutive or in a cerain range. The above values are just example values. It could be that we want the FirstIDs that have corresponding SecondIDs 1,10, 56 and not 5, 30

Comment: @Corcus . . . I enhanced the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think Gonzalo Lorieto proably has the best answer to this question already, but depending on the size of your data, `SELECT` statements in a `WHERE` clause can get really slow, and the below might be significantly faster (although it's not clear it's worth it for the reduced readability...)

```
SELECT inrange.FirstId FROM 
t inrange
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT FirstID FROM t
WHERE SEcondId IN (4,5)) outrange
ON inrange.firstID = outrange.firstId
WHERE SecondID IN (1,2,3)
AND outrange.firstId IS NULL
GROUP BY inrange.FirstId
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause to exclude the FirstIDs that have an invalid SecondID.  here is an example:

```
SELECT FirstID from test Has123
WHERE SecondID IN (1,2,3)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM test Not45 
  WHERE Has123.FirstID = Not45.FirstID 
  AND Not45.SecondID IN (4,5)
)
GROUP BY FirstID
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd607/4)